# Google Cloud SQL - Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I am following the link below to create a Cloud SQL Proxy.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-container-engine

When I get to the step to create the service account, I am unable to see any Cloud SQL roles, even though I have a MySQL instance associated with the project and I have enabled Cloud SQL administration API as described in the previous step.

Also, the whole process seems to be quite long-winded. Is there a way to connect directly from the container cluster to Cloud SQL without using the proxy? If yes, how do I find the IP address of the Cloud SQL instance? Also, how do I get the container cluster IP to white-list?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the roles you see in IAM settings?

Comment: Please visit this page and make sure the Cloud SQL service is enabled: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sql-component.googleapis.com/overview